# C calculation errors

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that will calculate various values for a simple circuit, but none of the calculations are providing the correct answer.  This is where the problem is:

```
void input();
void current(double,double,double);
void voltage1(double,double,double);

void input()
{
    double voltage;
    double R1;
    double R2;
    int selection;

    //I'm not entirely sure why the & signs need to be where they are, but the program won't run past here without them.
    scanf("%d",voltage);
    scanf("%d",&R1);
    scanf("%d",&R2);
    selection = menu(); //menu is a separate method that does work for selecting what to calculate.

    switch (selection)
    {
    case 1:
        current(voltage,R1,R2);
        break;
    case 2:
        voltage1(voltage,R1,R2);
        break;
    } //end of switch selection
} //end of input

void current(double voltage,double R1,double R2)
{
    double I = voltage / (R1 + R2);
    printf("%d",I);
} //end of current

void voltage1(double voltage,double R1,double R2)
{
    double V1 = (voltage * R1) / (R1 + R2)
    printf("%d",V1);
} //end of voltage1
```

Using 10 for voltage, R1, and R2 should return 1 for current and 5 for voltage, but I will consistently get 789577626 for current, and 0 for voltage.  current is always somewhere around the value I get for 10, 5 and 5, will voltage1 will always be 0.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful for you to read the manual page for `scanf`. Also you need an `&` in front of `voltage`

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings - it will save you time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `scanf` and `printf` format specifiers don't match the types you're using. `%d` is for `signed int` types, but you use `double`. You need to use `%a`, `%A`, `%e`, `%E`, `%f`, `%F`, `%g`, or `%G`.

Comment: `%f` , etc. will not work for `double voltage;`.  OP needs `scanf("%lf", &voltage);`

Comment: Good call. Forgot about `scanf` being different.